# RenderScript not generating output

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm new to RenderScript on Android and I'm trying to set up the most basic "hello world" kind of usage of RenderScript to process a bitmap image.  This minimal example is supposed to just set the output bitmap to a solid color (red) and ignore the input image.

Here is my Kotlin code that is called from my MainActivity.

```kotlin
        var rs = RenderScript.create(this)
        val script = ScriptC_simple_effect(rs)

        val conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        val width = 2
        val height = 2
        val inbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, conf)
        val outbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, conf)

        var inAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inbmp)
        var outAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outbmp)
        
        inAllocation.copyFrom(inbmp)
        script.forEach_makeRed(inAllocation, outAllocation)
        outAllocation.copyTo(outbmp)

        val pixels = IntArray(width * height)
        outbmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, outbmp.width, 0, 0, width, height)
```

And here is the simple_effect renderscript code

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz) // redacted

uchar4 RS_KERNEL makeRed(uchar4 in)
{
    uchar4 out;
    out.r = 255;
    out.g = 0;
    out.b = 0;
    out.a = 255;
    return out;
}
```

build.gradle includes the following in the android defaultConfig section.

```
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

I was expecting to see my final output bitmap contain all RED colored pixels.

Actually results are that all the Ints of the output pixels IntArray are 0 when running in the emulator or are all -1 (0xFFFFFFFF) when running on an actual device.  I get no run-time errors or warnings.

What did I do wrong?  Why am I not getting output?

*(Can you tell from this code? If the problem might be elsewhere, please let me know what additional information might be required.)*

#### Edit: Update

It turns out that if I include in my build.gradle:

```
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

... and I use these imports:

```kotlin
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.renderscript.Allocation
import androidx.renderscript.RenderScript
```

... then it **doesn't work correctly**.  The output is just white.

But if I remove the `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled` declaration, and change the renderscript imports from `androidx.` to just `android.`, then it **does work correctly** and the output is red as intended.

```kotlin
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.renderscript.Allocation
import android.renderscript.RenderScript
```

I'm confused as to why.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `outbmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)`? Offset and Stride parameters should be zero as you aren't trying to get a subset.

Comment: I've tested your code, and it works correctly, it produces a red bitmap. In addition I also verified that the pixels returned by getPixels are also red. You can check it yourself while debugging. Place a breakpoint after the "copyTo", and in the debug inspector you will see a "view" option right beside the bitmap objects which allows you to preview the actual Bitmap in debug mode. So the issue must be somewhere else, as your code works as expected.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, If I set the stride argument to 0 as you show, I get the run-time error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: abs(stride) must be >= width`

Comment: @PerracoLabs That's really useful information!  Thanks for trying it.  The "view" option on my outbmp shows that the bitmap gets set to all white.  I guess I have more debugging to do.  Not sure where to look next.

Comment: @Wyck That is weird, the code is quite simple and straight forward. What I did is to create a brand-new project, copy/paste your code and script, and it works perfect. I have tried with the gradle renderscript support options, and without. And in both scenarios works perfect. Maybe you should try the same, create an empty project with nothing else at all other than your renderscript code. If it is of any use, I've done the test with the emulator configured as Pixel 3a API 29.

Comment: I found a workaround, which was to **remove** `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled` as suggested [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140083#comment26).  But it doesn't explain to me why it doesn't work with `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled`.